# how to display google map in between the dashboard

Tags: python, google-maps, flask, jinja2

while running flask server throwing this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null     at Object._.Og (js?key=AIzaSyAbZKo3h1LVhyoURgxcSUG9BGVvZtZpg0U:88)     at new Sg (js?key=AIzaSyAbZKo3h1LVhyoURgxcSUG9BGVvZtZpg0U:89)
I'm new google maps in Python-Flask.google map is not showing while running the Flask localhost server.but,it showing while running the template.i'm not aware where i have mistaken in my source code. I need only show the map in between the empty place. here is the dashboard  [where place be the map here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iekCJ.png)

yesterday i posted answer that is working.but it's showing like Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null     at Object._.Og (js?key=AIzaSyAbZKo3h1LVhyoURgxcSUG9BGVvZtZpg0U:88)     at new Sg (js?key=AIzaSyAbZKo3h1LVhyoURgxcSUG9BGVvZtZpg0U:89)  where is the problem

Here is the google map code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
{{super()}}
{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
{{super()}}
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<div class="row">
 <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">
        <em class="fa fa-home"></em>
    </a></li>
    <li class="active">Locations>create locations</li>
  </ol>
 </div><!--/.row-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDv8X0eEAWUtWZrHG_1XLB8gMNxgdcD0-U"></script>
<script >
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.3850, 78.4867),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
        var name;
        var lat;
        var lng;
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());
            var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Hello World!'
        });

            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[1]) {

                    name= results[1].formatted_address;
                    lat=e.latLng.lat();
                    lng=e.latLng.lng();
                        alert("Location: " +name + "\r\nLatitude: " + lat + "\r\nLongitude: " +lng );
                   document.getElementById("loc").value=name;
                    document.getElementById("lat").value=lat;
                     document.getElementById("lng").value=lng;

                    }
                }

            });
        });
    }
</script>
<!--<div id="dvMap" style="width: 50%; height: 50%">-->
<!--</div>-->
<form   role="form" action="/post/locations" method="post"  >
<input type="text" id="loc" name="name" class="form-control"/>
<input type="text" name="latitude" id="lat" class="form-control"/>
<input name="longitude" id="lng" type="text" class="form-control"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                                        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">

</form>

</div>

</div>
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 80%; height: 70%   ">
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the Python code:

```
@app.route('/page/locations')
  def location():
  if session['username']:
      return render_template('map.html',user=session['username'])

  else:
    print ('login first!')
    return redirect('/dashboard')
```

Comment: please give me your suggestion or any idea for that .

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer.Here it is my answer.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
{{super()}}
{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
{{super()}}
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}



<div class="row">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">
        <em class="fa fa-home"></em>
    </a></li>
    <li class="active">Locations>Create Locations</li>
 </ol>
 </div><!--/.row  id="entry.id" id="uploadbanner"-->


 <div id="dvMap" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
 </div>

<form role="form" action="/post/locations" method="post">
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="loc" name="name"/>
<label>Latitude:</label>
<input type="text" name="latitude" id="lat"/>
<label>Longitude:</label>
<input name="longitude" id="lng" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value=" Submit ">
<input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

I just add the script in Javascript folder .

as a like <--static/assets/js/map.js --> in my template base.html source code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the javascript snippet is getting executed before the div element ( one with id="dvMap" ) is created. So either place the javascript snippet after the div element like below,

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
{{super()}}
{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
{{super()}}
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<div class="row">
 <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">
        <em class="fa fa-home"></em>
    </a></li>
    <li class="active">Locations>create locations</li>
  </ol>
 </div>{# /.row  #}
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">

{# <div id="dvMap" style="width: 50%; height: 50%"></div> #}
<form   role="form" action="/post/locations" method="post"  >
<input type="text" id="loc" name="name" class="form-control"/>
<input type="text" name="latitude" id="lat" class="form-control"/>
<input name="longitude" id="lng" type="text" class="form-control"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                                        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">

</form>

</div>

</div>
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 80%; height: 70%   ">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDv8X0eEAWUtWZrHG_1XLB8gMNxgdcD0-U"></script>
    <script >
        window.onload = function () {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.3850, 78.4867),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
            var name;
            var lat;
            var lng;
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());
                var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Hello World!'
            });

                geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[1]) {

                        name= results[1].formatted_address;
                        lat=e.latLng.lat();
                        lng=e.latLng.lng();
                            alert("Location: " +name + "\r\nLatitude: " + lat + "\r\nLongitude: " +lng );
                       document.getElementById("loc").value=name;
                        document.getElementById("lat").value=lat;
                         document.getElementById("lng").value=lng;

                        }
                    }

                });
            });
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Or make a separate js file ( here I have named it custom.js for an example ) in the static folder with the javascript code in it and add `<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='custom.js') }}'></script>` at the end of the file.

I hope this helps you.

PS :- Please use the jinja2 comment tags while commenting in jinja2 template file. You can refer it [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#comments).

Comment: it's thrown this error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
    at Object._.Og (js?key=AIzaSyAbZKo3h1LVhyoURgxcSUG9BGVvZtZpg0U:88)
    at new Sg (js?key=AIzaSyAbZKo3h1LVhyoURgxcSUG9BGVvZtZpg0U:89)
    at window.onload (map.js:13)

Comment: Try adding the maps api script file in the start of the template